# Monitor power consumption of a USB port

Tags: usb, power

I have a device attached to a Usb port and want to run some tests to see the power required for the device to function correctly. I wanted to know if there is any software which will tell me how much power the usb device is actually consuming. I have tried going to Device Manager and generic usb hub and select the power tab. However the value is kind of constant and does not refresh. Are there any other alternatives for me? I have looked at this question posted in 2012 [Is there a USB power consumption meter?](https://superuser.com/questions/434354/is-there-an-usb-power-consumption-metre) but was hoping that someone could tell me how to do it since I need to analyze the device and plot graphs for it under different conditions of operation

Comment: A hardware tester is the best way to accomplish this. Depending on the tester you may be able to output data/reports to a PC that you can then aggregate and analyse.

Comment: I guess thats the only way to go.